# NSScrollView padding

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an NSScrollView with an NSTableView inside.

[image]

As you can see, there is a 100px high NSView that overlays the table view. (This is done intentionally, the overlay is slightly transparent and you can see a shadow of the table view scroll underneath).

The problem of course is that I need to add 100px of empty space to the bottom of the scroll view to compensate for the overlay. Otherwise you can't see the bottom of the table, it gets covered up by the overlay.

I've tried modifying the clip view, but seem to only be able to change its frame (losing the transparent overlay effect).

Maybe I'm not doing it quite right, please help!

Comment: Just a thought. What if you increase scrollViews contentSize by 100px after you do reloadData. Another thought would be to add empty row to match overlay.

Comment: @EvgeniyShurakov I tried subclassing the scroll view and overriding the `contentSize` method and adding 100px to the height. Is that the correct way to do this? It had no effect for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, I needed to consistently enlarge the `documentView` frame.

The best way I found to do this was to subclass the document view, which in this case is the NSTableView.

In the subclassed NSTableView I overrode the `setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize`

```
- (void)setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize {
    newSize.height += 100;
    [super setFrameSize:newSize];
}
```

Which added 100px of padding to the bottom of the table view and thus the scroll view.

Comment: What about the NSScroller? Does it properly stop at the upper edge of the music controls view? Or will that view overlap the NSScroller?

Comment: @Raffael The scroller does end up overlapping the music controls view, which isn't ideal, but it's not awful either. If you find a better way to do this, I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: I'd love to tell you a better way, but I'm also searching for one :P.

Comment: @Raffael in this case the music controls view overlaps the nsscrollview, so the scroller is acting as it was programmed to. If you wanted the scroll bar to stop artificially high, I'd imagine you'd have to also subclass the NSScroller and modify its drawing code.

Comment: Thanks, however I set up a new thread for my special case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233180/shrink-nsscroller-of-nsscrollview-in-layer-backed-view

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same thing in **Swift 4**:

```
class TableViewPadded: NSTableView{
  //Add padding at bottom
  override func setFrameSize(_ newSize: NSSize) {
    let padded = NSSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height+30)
    super.setFrameSize(padded)
  }
}
```